# Notions of Computability at Higher Type III

Tags: reference-request, computability, pl.programming-languages

I've recently found a very nice survey paper called "Notions of Computability at Higher Type" by John R. Longley.

The paper says it is part of a 3-part series, with the 3rd concerning non-extensional notions of computability, corresponding to computability in languages with effects.

This part might be relevant to my own research so I'm very interested in finding it.
However, I can't find a version of part III anywhere. Was it ever completed? If not is there another good resource on the subject you would recommend?

Comment: Why not ask J. Longley:  jrl@inf.ed.ac.uk. He's also got a book out on the subject [Higher-Order Computability](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662479919).

Comment: Yeah, instead of writing part III he wrote a book with Dag Normann.